# Calculate the average of an ever growing list

Tags: algorithm

How can I calculate the average of an ever growing list?

To elaborate: I have rough accelerometer data, returned as a double from `10` to `15` times a second. How to find the average at a given moment in time?

The solution that comes to my mind is storing the sum returned and its count, then dividing it every time, but this leads to buffer overflows and inaccurate results, since computers have issues with decimal numbers.

Please propose an algorithm or mathematical formula.

Comment: Use exact arithmetic? There's a formula for online average that eliminates the risk of overflow, but there's not a lot that can be done about "inaccurate results" in floating-point.

Comment: Probably a good middle ground might be reached by adding upper and lower thresholds to your summation first to zone in more on the region you're interested in?  Perhaps even going as far as to generate a deviation?

Comment: Are you sure that you want, at any given moment, the average from the beginning? bc usually in similar situations what matters is a moving average, which is easier to track and has the advantage of giving more importance to latest samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John D. Cook has a [very good post](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/standard_deviation/) on computing mean and standard deviation with stronger numerical properties.

Basically (reducing all the complexity) it can be as simple as this python code (imagine `data` as an infinite iterable):

```py
n = 0
mean = 0

for value in data:
    n += 1
    mean += (value - mean) / n
```

Answer (score 1):

Incremental average from here [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106700/incremental-averageing)

Using incrental average allows the new average to be calculated from the previous average + new value. This will be faster, and not generate massive numbers.

The second form on the page addresses precision concerns

Comment: Your link has http twice. +1 btw :p

Comment: I don't need to know my average in advance, my problem is that adding all these numbers 10-15 times a second ends in buffer overflow.